# How to resolve module name conflict in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have two module with the exact same name that belongs to two different apps, these two module are functionally quite similar except for the styling. I am creating a master component and try to import these two different module based on what app I am currently in.

I wonder if there is a way to conditionally import the module that I don't have to hard code a name space for the module, like `module_app1` and `module_app2` but instead to do

```
if (cond) {
    import module from 'path1';
} else {
    import module from 'path2';
}
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I use 'as'. Example:

```
import Actions from '../actions';
import { Actions as Navigator } from 'react-native-router-flux';
```